# mod re-write for clean API end point

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I have built a rest api and the end point is as

```
/var/www/site/restapi/v1
```

Now in the virtual host configuration I set something like

```
Alias /api/v1 /var/www/site/restapi/v1
```

so if I use the url
http://site.com/api/v1 it falls back to the index.php file inside `/restapi/v1`

But the API calls could be as
http://site.com/api/v1/Auth/login and to handle that I put the `.htacess` inside `/restapi/v1` as

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) index.php?resource=$1&method=$2
```

And it does not work. I did some research and found that in the virtual host config if I change the

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
```

to

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
```

Then it works but the issue is when I get the resource using GET then it becomes

```
"Auth/login"
```

How can I add the clean api url without having to remove MultiViews and using the re-write with

```
index.php?resource=$1&method=$2
```

Comment: What do you mean with "it becomes "Auth/login""? That sentence does not mean much to me. Also, try to be a bit more specific than "does not work" -- describe what happened instead.

Comment: Ok for "Auth/login" means inside the /restapi/v1 I have index.php file and when I use $resource = $_GET["resource"] the $resource contains "Auth/login", this happens when I takeout  MultiViews. If I keep MultiViews then I get 404 page not found error.

Comment: Here is an example I call an api method as http://site.com/api/v1/Auth/login. In the virtual host I have Alias /api/v1 /var/www/site/restapi/v1 and inside the restapi/v1 folder I have index.php file. The index.php gets the value of resource and method and for this I added the .htaccess with the rewrite rule as RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) index.php?resource=$1&method=$2 in /restapi/v1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly and the problem is that `$resource` includes also the method, then try changing the first capture group like this

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*) index.php?resource=$1&method=$2 [QSA]
```

or use lazy matching instead (`.*?`).

I don't know why MultiViews would conflict; possibly you have some other files with names that conflict. Check your log files, possibly after increasing the verbosity level.

Comment: you rock. This works now with the rewrite rule given by you. The page not found issue was due to the fact I have a class called Auth.class.php inside the /restapi/v1 folder and as you explained it was the same name file which was causing the issue. I have moved all the class to a subfolder and all seems working now. Thanks a lot for your help :)